# Conserved currents in the Standard Model

Tags: conservation-laws, standard-model, gauge-theory, symmetry-breaking, gauge-invariance

As we know, the gauge bosons $W^{\pm}, Z$ and $\gamma$ couple to currents in the Standard Model. Now my question is are these currents conserved? 
I mean, there is no doubt about the electromagnetic current. However, what about the currents $J_{\pm}$ and $J_{Z}$? As far as I know, by the [Weinberg-Witten theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem), they should not satisfy the relation $\partial_{\mu} J^{\mu } =0 $ before the spontaneous symmetry breaking. I guess the acquirance of mass changes things, since the Weinberg-Witten theorem is not valid now? But then, how can we see that now the currents are conserved after the gauge bosons acquired masses? I think I am mainly confusing the symmetries before the SSB and after the SSB, but I do not know how to look at this problem.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153889/what-does-weinberg-witten-theorem-want-to-express). The currents of the SM are conserved before and after SSB.

Comment: [See this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303706/do-conservation-laws-still-hold-for-spontaneously-broken-symmetries).